# Something going wrong while making my progress bar in GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

After I succeeded in making a progress bar in console, I thought about upgrading the program to GUI.

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
class Progress(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.value = 1
        self.endvalue = 100
        self.bar_length = 20

        self.label1 = Label(self)
        self.label1.grid()

        self.button1 = Button(self, text = "Start", command = self.startprogress())
        self.button.grid()
    def startprogress(self):
        while self.value <= self.endvalue:
            root.after(100, self.updateprogress)
    def updateprogress(self):
        percent = float(self.value) / self.endvalue
        arrow = '|' * int(round(percent * self.bar_length)-1) + '|'
        spaces = ' ' * (self.bar_length - len(arrow))
        self.label1.configure( text = "Percent: [{0}] {1}%".format(arrow + spaces, int(round(percent * 100))) )
        self.value+=1

root = Tk()
root.title("Progress")
app = Progress(root)
root.mainloop()
```

When I start the program, It does nothing; no error, no window going up.

I started debugging it, trying to understand the problem. If I erase all the code under the `__init__` function, the window would go up. For that I think maybe the `while` loop is the problem here.

Can someone tell me whats the problem in this program?

Comment: Don't _call_ the function that you're trying to connect to an event handler for christssake. Maybe in a thousand years people will finally understand this concept... `command = self.startprogress()` -> `command = self.startprogress`.

Comment: Did it. The window came up, but when I press Start, the whole program just freezes

Comment: Your `startprogress` function queues a trillion `self.updateprogress` with `root.after(100, self.updateprogress)` before `self.value` is ever incremented. Get rid of the loop and just do `root.after(100, self.updateprogress)` at the bottom of `updateprogress`.

Comment: But i need the loop to finish the progress

Comment: it worked. thank you!

Comment: can you post a answer of this so i can mark it?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#progressbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this code:

```
def startprogress(self):
    while self.value <= self.endvalue:
        root.after(100, self.updateprogress)
```

This is an infinite loop. I hope I don't need to explain why.

What you probably wanted to do is this:

```
def startprogress(self):
    # queue ONE call to self.updateprogress
    root.after(100, self.updateprogress)

def updateprogress(self):
    percent = float(self.value) / self.endvalue
    arrow = '|' * int(round(percent * self.bar_length)-1) + '|'
    spaces = ' ' * (self.bar_length - len(arrow))
    self.label1.configure( text = "Percent: [{0}] {1}%".format(arrow + spaces, int(round(percent * 100))) )
    self.value+=1

    # now that self.value has been incremented, queue ANOTHER call
    if self.value <= self.endvalue:
        root.after(100, self.updateprogress)
```

Comment: exactly what I did. Thank you

Comment: Not only is it an infinite loop, it is an infinite loop that creates infinite loops.

Comment: `command = self.startprogress()` being part of the original problem could be also explained.